# PHP Crawler missing Hits and empty Hits

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am making a PHP crawler that crawls a url for Email addresses. But somehow it is missing emails addresses and it returns empty arrays places.

code:

```
function curl($url){
        $ch = curl_init( );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        return $return;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['go']))
    {
        if($_POST['url'] != ''){
        $data = curl($_POST['url']);
        preg_match("/[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})/i", $data, $matches);
        echo "<h1>Handmatig gezocht</h1><hr>";
        $tely = count($matches);
        for ($y=0; $y<=$tely; $y++) 
        {
            if(!empty($matches[$y]))
            {
                echo $matches[$y] ."<br>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Lege array :(<br>";
            }   
        }
        echo "<hr>";

        }
    }
```

I made a simple webpage on my local host with 5 emails

```
    <p>jamie@jamie.nl</p>
    <p>test@test.nl</p>
    <p>dasd@dsad.nl</p>
    <p>addasd@dasvfv.nl</p>
    <p>gsdgseg@sdfsdfsd.nl</p>
```

And the array i get back from my crawler looks likes this :

```
Array ( [0] => jamie@jamie.nl [1] => [2] => [3] => .nl )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you are using preg_match (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)).
You should use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead.